# Can't set color to JPanel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have just started with Graphics in java, and I'm already stuck. I have tried to set the color of the JPanel to red but nothing seems to work! Any help is highly appreciated.

JFrame class:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;


public class redBoxFrame{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(400, 200);
        f.setTitle("A red box");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new redBoxPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.RED);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

JPanel class:

```
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import java.awt.Color;

  public class redBoxPanel extends JPanel {

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
     g.setColor(Color.RED);

     }
  }
```

As you can see I have both tried to declare the color in the JFrame class and in the JPanel class but none of them seem to work. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone here seems to miss the fact that the colour should be set **before** drawing.

I'll set the main background to BLUE for demo purposes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...
    JPanel p = new redBoxPanel();
    // BLUE bg. This covers the whole panel.
    p.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //...
}
```

And now for the red box!

```
public static class redBoxPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // You need to call the superclass' paintComponent() so that the 
        // setBackground() you called in main() is painted.
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // You need to set the colour BEFORE drawing your rect
        g.setColor(Color.RED);

        // Now that we have a colour, perform the drawing
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

        // More, for fun
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also very nice of you that you added a few tricks like drawing a line across the box and adding comments describing what you do! I appreciate it very much : ) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you you are missing `super.paintComponent(g);` in your painComponent method.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but it undforgunately does not seem to work, I tried updating the code to                                                           g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
super.paintComponent(g);
g.setColor(Color.RED);   But now the whole frame turns red! You don't happen to have another idea? Thanks!

Comment: @First75 was on the right track i believe. You have to call super.paintComponent(g); but this has to be the first line before you do the fillRect and the setColor

Comment: Aha okay! well now everything but the JPanel is red... So the JFrame is red and the panel remains dark gray. You don't happen to know something I might do to get only the box red? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Believe that the solution is working however you are, like you said in your question, setting the background in the JFrame class and the JPanel class.
if you remove the setBackground from the JFrame class you should see only the rectangle that you are drawing. Please try the below solution and let us know if it works.

JFrame class:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;


public class redBoxFrame{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(400, 200);
        f.setTitle("A red box");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new redBoxPanel();
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

JPanel class:

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import java.awt.Color;

  public class redBoxPanel extends JPanel {

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
     g.setColor(Color.RED);

     }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do it either, unforgunately. It still renders the box as dark gray... You don't happen to have another trick I could try? also, If it worked for you maybe there is a problem with my IDE or something on my end? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Didn't test it to be honest. I will have a look later today if I get time